# Переход по бинарному дереву

Tags: c++, бинарное-дерево

Ребят, такая проблема, при прохождении по дереву выдаёт исключение и завершает работу с ошибкой, хотя условие указано. Я понимаю, что проблема в том, что следующий элемент NULL, но не знаю как это исправить? Заранее извиняюсь за корявый, некрасивый код

```
int amount = 0;
void FindAmountGivenKey(char numberKey, Branch* aBranch)
{    
    if (aBranch->LeftBranch != nullptr && aBranch->Data == numberKey) { //ERROR!!!!!!!!!!!!
        amount++;
    }
        FindAmountGivenKey(numberKey, aBranch->LeftBranch);

     if (aBranch->RightBranch != nullptr && aBranch->Data == numberKey) {
            amount++;
        }
        FindAmountGivenKey(numberKey, aBranch->RightBranch);
    
    return ;
}
```

Comment: @CrazyElf  забыл, извините

Comment: как минимум в начале не хватает условия вида `if (aBranch == nullptr) return;`

Comment: я убрал в условии `aBranch->LeftBranch != nullptr` и `aBranch->RightBranch!= nullptr` и всё заработало

Comment: @KoVadim я не могу найти кнопку, лучший ответ, новичок на этом сайте)

Comment: а его нет, так как я не давал ответ, я сделал просто комментарий:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В большинстве случаев, если в функцию прилетает указатель, то хорошо бы его сразу проверить на nullptr. Где то так

```
{    
    if (aBranch == nullptr) return;
    if (aBranch->LeftBranch != nullptr && aBranch->Data == numberKey) { 
        amount++;
    }
        FindAmountGivenKey(numberKey, aBranch->LeftBranch);

     if (aBranch->RightBranch != nullptr && aBranch->Data == numberKey) {
            amount++;
        }
        FindAmountGivenKey(numberKey, aBranch->RightBranch);
    
    return ;
}
```

отдельно замечу, что если написать вот так

```
if (aBranch->LeftBranch != nullptr && aBranch->Data == numberKey && aBranch != nullptr)
```

хоть и выглядит похоже, но работать не будет так как нужно. Самое интересное, что после того, как компилятор видит разыменование, он имеет право считать, что указатель уже не nullptr и проверять на это уже не нужно:)